# removing entire line with sed using wild characters

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

```
E219 E36 C5X       
C201 C19 C5X

E229 E36 C5X  
E239 E36 C5X  
C311 C19 C5X
```

In this file example, I need to remove all lines containing C[0-9][0-9][0-9]. How I can do this with sed command? The output should be:

```
E219 E36 C5X       
E229 E36 C5X  
E239 E36 C5X
```

I tried the following code:

```
 sed -i '/^C[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/d' data
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried the following code: sed -i '/^C[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/d' data but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchors `^` and `$` make your expression only match lines that consist entirely of a *single* 4-character sequence `C[0-9][0-9][0-9]` whereas your `data` file has lines containing multiple sequences (and possibly some trailing whitespace). If you relax that restriction it will work, either

```
sed '/^C[0-9][0-9][0-9]/d' data
```

(match only at the start of a line) or

```
sed '/C[0-9][0-9][0-9]/d' data
```

(match anywhere in a line). If you also want to remove empty lines as shown in your example, then

```
sed -e '/C[0-9][0-9][0-9]/d' -e '/^$/d' data
```